# Unable to set width when styling the title attribute

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to style the title attribute of the anchor tag, but instead of styling the title attribute, I am using my own `data-title` attribute.

But, I am unable to set width for it. The value of the `data-title` just overflows the container, how to fix the problem.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rohitink/hkDjk/

Comment: It's because `white-space: nowrap;` is preventing the text from wrapping onto a new line, causing it to overflow the containing element. [Removing that](http://jsfiddle.net/hkDjk/5/) allows the content to be contained but introduces the problem of words being broken.

Comment: I never knew you could do content: attr(whatever); thats awesome.

Comment: the Content property is very flexible: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Comment: Damn it. that is so embarrasing for me. I can not tell you :(

Comment: The question title is seriously misleading. You are *not* trying to style the `title` attribute.

Comment: The question should include the relevant code. Referring to a jsfiddle is nice, but not sufficient.